# Adding Search to Custom SimpleAdapter for Custom Listview

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, simpleadapter

I have a ListView working absolutely fine . now i want to add search facility On some textview of the listItem row.

For Example i have a editText or Searchview in toolbar. 
and my ListView has one of the item , that is status field . now i want search only for status from the listview .

I found many solutions on the internet , but i have my custom simple adapter class i have no idea how to add search in it .

Here is MY ExtendedSimpleAdapter code :

```
public class ExtendedSimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter implements Filterable {
List<? extends Map<String, ?>> map; // if fails to compile, replace with List<HashMap<String, Object>> map


String[] from;
int layout;
int[] to;
private ArrayList<Map<String, ?>> mUnfilteredData;
//private ArrayList<Product> mDisplayedValues;
Context context;
private Filter mFilter;
LayoutInflater mInflater;

public ExtendedSimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, // if fails to compile, do the same replacement as above on this line
                             int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    layout = resource;
    map = data;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return map.size();
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return map.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    return this.createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, layout);
}


private View createViewFromResource(int position, View convertView,
                                    ViewGroup parent, int resource) {
    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    } else {
        v = convertView;
    }

    this.bindView(position, v);

    return v;
}


private void bindView(int position, View view) {
    final Map dataSet = map.get(position);
    if (dataSet == null) {
        return;
    }

    final ViewBinder binder = super.getViewBinder();
    final int count = to.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View v = view.findViewById(to[i]);
        if (v != null) {
            final Object data = dataSet.get(from[i]);
            String text = data == null ? "" : data.toString();
            if (text == null) {
                text = "";
            }

            boolean bound = false;
            if (binder != null) {
                bound = binder.setViewValue(v, data, text);
            }

            if (!bound) {
                if (v instanceof Checkable) {
                    if (data instanceof Boolean) {
                        ((Checkable) v).setChecked((Boolean) data);
                    } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                        // Note: keep the instanceof TextView check at the bottom of these
                        // ifs since a lot of views are TextViews (e.g. CheckBoxes).
                        setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() +
                                " should be bound to a Boolean, not a " +
                                (data == null ? "<unknown type>" : data.getClass()));
                    }
                } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
                    // Note: keep the instanceof TextView check at the bottom of these
                    // ifs since a lot of views are TextViews (e.g. CheckBoxes).
                    setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                } else if (v instanceof ImageView) {
                    if (data instanceof Integer) {
                        setViewImage((ImageView) v, (Integer) data);
                    } else if (data instanceof Bitmap) {
                        setViewImage((ImageView) v, (Bitmap) data);
                    } else {
                        setViewImage((ImageView) v, text);
                    }
                } else if (v instanceof RatingBar) {
                    float score = Float.parseFloat(data.toString());  //2
                    ((RatingBar) v).setRating(score);
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() + " is not a " +
                            " view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


private void setViewImage(ImageView v, Bitmap bmp) {
    v.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    if (mFilter == null) {
        mFilter = new SimpleFilter();
    }
    return mFilter;
}

private class SimpleFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (mUnfilteredData == null) {
            mUnfilteredData = new ArrayList<Map<String, ?>>(map);
        }

        if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
            ArrayList<Map<String, ?>> list = mUnfilteredData;
            results.values = list;
            results.count = list.size();
        } else {
            String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

            ArrayList<Map<String, ?>> unfilteredValues = mUnfilteredData;
            int count = unfilteredValues.size();

            ArrayList<Map<String, ?>> newValues = new ArrayList<Map<String, ?>>(count);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Map<String, ?> h = unfilteredValues.get(i);
                if (h != null) {

                    int len = to.length;

                    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                        String str = (String) h.get(from[j]);

                        String[] words = str.split(" ");
                        int wordCount = words.length;

                        for (int k = 0; k < wordCount; k++) {
                            String word = words[k];

                            if (word.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefixString)) {
                                newValues.add(h);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            results.values = newValues;
            results.count = newValues.size();
        }

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        //noinspection unchecked
        map = (List<Map<String, ?>>) results.values;
        if (results.count > 0) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }


}
```

}

Here i am setting the adapter to listview :

```
 evc = new ExtendedSimpleAdapter(Users.this, contactList,R.layout.new_dr_list,
                new String[]{"picture","name","speciality" ,"status","education","experience","rating"},
                new int[]{R.id.imug_p1,R.id.usr_dname,R.id.dspecs,R.id.statusp,R.id.educ,R.id.exper,R.id.ratingBar1});
        usersList.setAdapter(evc);
        ((BaseAdapter) evc).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

As you can see i have one tag status in simpleadapter , HOW can i Perform search on it..??

**Edit**

Now I am geting this error when i search something from searview bar.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.adnan.zwd.hidoctor.Chat.ExtendedSimpleAdapter.getCount(ExtendedSimpleAdapter.java:52)
                                                                           at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:739)
                                                                           at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AdapterView.java:862)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AbsListView.java:6211)
                                                                           at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated(DataSetObservable.java:50)
                                                                           at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(BaseAdapter.java:59)
                                                                           at com.adnan.zwd.hidoctor.Chat.ExtendedSimpleAdapter$SimpleFilter.publishResults(ExtendedSimpleAdapter.java:222)
                                                                           at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if(from[i].contains(constraints)) within a cicle, save the results in an String[] and finally assign that array to the Adapter so it work with it. However I recomend you to change to ReciclerView instead of ListView.

the example ... didn't test it but should work or at least help you.. i hope. funny fact ... I learn couple things too from your code. so thanks for the oportunity.

```
 @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            from = (String[]) results.values; // change dateset
              notifyDataSetChanged();
                 // notifies the data with new filtered values
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new Filter.FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
               // ArrayList<Product> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<Product>();

             String [] filtered = new String[from.length];
                int index=0;
              for(int i=0;i<from.length;i++)
                  if(from[i].contains(constraint))
                  {
                      filtered[index++]=from[i];
                  }
                results.values = filtered;
                results.count=index;

                return results;
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
```

Comment: can you provide any example ? i am new to custom Adapters.. Even i found recyclerView really difficult to go with me , Kindly suggest how should i make it work. thanks

Comment: that's because i updated the datasource but didn't update the `List<? extends Map<String, ?>> map;` object,sorry my bad, and you use that to get the amount of objects in your dataset, in fact probably by just updating the "map" you could get it to work. So in publishResults() place your code for map to have only the filtered results.